# Why does checking for a null parameter in a select statement cause the query to execute so much slower?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have a database with 1,941,092 rows in it, and a clustered columnstore index. I noticed some strange behavior when querying it the other day, and wanted an explanation, so I wrote some queries to isolate the issue.

**Query A**

```
DECLARE @loannumber INT = 2222222;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    MASDATA_CURRENT.BDE.LOAN
WHERE
    @loanNumber IS NULL
    OR LOAN_NUMBER = @loanNumber;
```

**Query B**

```
DECLARE @loannumber INT = 2222222;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    MASDATA_CURRENT.BDE.LOAN
WHERE
    LOAN_NUMBER = @loanNumber;
```

Both queries produce the same result set. The elapsed time for query A is 1 minute, 39 seconds; the elapsed time for Query B is 11 seconds. From what I can tell, Query B, which doesn’t check for a null parameter, executes 87% faster.

The execution plans for the queries are as follows:

```
Query A                            | Query B
-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------
Select                             | Select
Cost: 0%                           | Cost: 0%
-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------
Filter                             | Parallelism 
Cost: 6%                           | (Gather Streams)
                                   | Cost: 1%
-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------
Columnstore Index Scan (Clustered) | Columnstore Index Scan (Clustered) 
Cost: 94%                          | Cost: 99%
```

The statistics for the selects are as follows:

```
Statistic                | Query A | Query B |
-------------------------|---------|---------|
Cache Plan Size          |  224 KB |  432 KB |
Degree of Parallellism   |       1 |       8 |
Estimated Operator Cost  |  0 (0%) | 0 (0 %) |
Estimated Subtree Cost   |  22.103 | 6.32266 |
Estimated Number of Rows |  660449 | 1.00017 |
```

Executing the batches repeatedly shows the same results--caching does not appear to affect the outcome.

**The Question**

Why does checking for a null parameter produce such drastically different results?

Please note that I am not looking for alternative ways to write the query. I'm looking for an explanation for why this occurs.

Comment: Did you cleared buffer cache and plan cache before running both the queries

Comment: I am not sure about your case, but in the past I have achieved significant speedups by adding query hints. See this page, there are many kinds: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query

Comment: Do a lot of your rows  have a NULL value for that field?  Based on the statistics, it looks like about half of the rows are NULL.

Comment: Check out this article. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ It explains the reason this happens and has some excellent alternatives.

Comment: @BenRubin There are no rows in the table where LOAN_NUMBER evaluates to null. Even if that were the case, I'm not checking LOAN_NUMBER for null, but the loanNumber parameter.

Comment: @MikeHofer the link pointed by Sean Lange explains that the "null check" generates a bad execution plan, which is obvious from the estimated rows. *Why* do you want to use an "optional parameter"? How are you going to call this query? Why not use an ORM or Dapper from the client to *avoid* the WHERE statement entirely ?

Comment: have you tried changing the code to get rid of the or statement?

eg: 
DECLARE @loannumber INT = 2222222;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    MASDATA_CURRENT.BDE.LOAN
WHERE ISNULL(LOAN_NUMBER, @loanNumber) = @loanNumber;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erland Sommarskog [explains why](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) such catch-all queries are bad and offers several ways to fix them. In this particular case, the null check forces the query to run in row mode instead of batch mode.

If you check the operations in each of the execution plans, you'll see that the null check forces all operations in the execution plan to work in row mode. That means that SQL Server unpacks the columnstore index, reconstitues all rows and only then starts the scan and filter operation.

You'll see something like :

```
SELECT <- FILTER <- Columnstore Index Scan
```

If you hover over the Filter and Index Scan nodes, you'll see that the estimated execution mode is Row

Without the null check you'll have the following exeuction plan:

```
SELECT <- Parallelism <- Filter <- Columnstore Index scan
```

Filter and Index Scan in this case work in Batch mode, which means the server is able to actually use the columnstore dictionaries to find the one block that actually contains the parameter value.

As Erland Sommarskog suggests, you can use an `OPTIMIZE FOR` hint to have the optimizer generate an execution plan suitable for a specific parameter value. In this case, both queries will have the same execution plans that use Batch mode.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MASDATA_CURRENT.BDE.LOAN
WHERE
    @loanNumber IS NULL
    OR LOAN_NUMBER = @loanNumber
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@loanNumber = -1)) ;
```

Even with this fix, the query can become very complex, very quickly if you have many parameters. I wouldn't want to imagine what it would look like if you have anything more complex than straight OR or AND conditions.

A simpler solution though would be to get rid of "optional parameters" by using an ORM like EF or Dapper to generate the query on the client side. Both of them generate parameterized queries when needed, so you won't lose any performance or security benefits. The ORM will generate only the filter conditions you specify, so the query will be a lot simpler

Comment: I found that OPTION (RECOMPILE) produced the best performance. Oddly, when I used OPTIMIZE FOR (@loanNumber = x), the performance degraded.

Comment: would this work for a rowstore index? or is only for columnstore?

Comment: @rk13 the articles that explain what's wrong with catch-all queries were written before the introduction of columnstore indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Look at OR operator. The first condidion requieres to watch ALL records in table without any filters.
The server has to make the execution plan for this case, and just after that applyes second condition.